# Setting background colors depending on the value in MySQL database field

Tags: php, mysql, css

I've created a Ticketing System with PHP and a MySQL database.

On the view tickets page, I have each ticket in the database displaying, which includes a priority of each ticket. Priorities are set to either Low, Normal or High.

When the data pulls through to my page, it sets the priority inside a div to whatever it says in my database table.

I'm wanting to find a way to change the background color depending on what value is shown in the priority field, so red for high, orange for normal and green for low.

**HTML / PHP**

```
<div class="priority">
    <?php 
    $priority_query = "SELECT priority FROM tickets";
    $priority = mysql_query($priority_query);

    if ($priority = 'low') { ?>
    <div class="priority_low"><?php echo 'Priority: ' . mysql_result ($result,$j,'priority') .''; ?></div>

    <?php       
    } else if ($priority = 'normal') { ?>
        <div class="priority_normal"><?php echo 'Priority: ' . mysql_result($result,$j,'priority') .''; ?></div>

        <?php       
        } else if ($priority = 'high') { ?>
        <div class="priority_high"><?php echo 'Priority: ' . mysql_result($result,$j,'priority') .''; ?></div>

        <?php } ?>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.priority_low {
        background-color: green;
    }

.priority_normal {
        background-color: orange;
    }

.priority_high {
        background-color: red;
    }
```

I've tried the code above, but that only brings back a green background, which obviously isn't what I require.

Anybody have any ideas to make this work?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I managed to get it working, without needing to use a while loop.

Answer (score 4):

You're presently doing an assignment, rather than a comparison.

In `if ($priority = 'low')`.

It should read as `if ($priority == 'low')` with 2x equal signs.

- Do the same for the others.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

However, you need to loop over your results with a [`while()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) loop and an [`if()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) inside it.

I.e.:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($priority))  
{
    if(...) // your if conditions
}
```

and using `$row` rather than the query's `$priority` variable, which would have thrown you an error.

I.e.: `if ($row == 'low'){...}` *etc. etc. etc.*

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

---

**Footnotes:**

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.